# Illegal Offset Type Error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

So I've got the following function:

```
function sitesync_empty_vals(&$entity) {
  $vals = false;
  $entity = (array) $entity;
  foreach ($entity as $field) {
    if (is_array($field)) {
      foreach ($field as $lang) {
        foreach ($lang as $item) {
          if (isset($item['value'])) {
            if (empty($item['value'])) {
              unset($field[$lang][$item]);
              break;
            }
            else {
              $vals = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (!$vals && is_array($lang)) {
        watchdog("field", print_r($field, true));
        unset($field[$lang]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting the error `Illegal offset type`.

I'm not quite understanding why I'd be getting this error - it seems to be related to unsetting the `$field[$lang][$item]` (I don't get the error when I comment it out), but why would that be? Is it because it's trying to iterate over that item after it is unset? In the case that that particular value is empty, I want to unset the whole $item - this is for data normalization between two different servers, one of which doesn't store any data, and one of which stores the data as a 0.

Comment: This is for Drupal isn't it? You should add a Drupal tag and update the description with what version of Drupal you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   foreach ($lang as $item) {
             ^^^^---array

          unset($field[$lang][$item]);
                       ^^^^^---using Array as array key
```

You probably want something more like:

```
foreach($lang as $lang_key => $item) {
      unset($field[$lang_key]....);
```

instead. And as the comments below have noted, `$item` is ALSO an array, so you'll want a similar treatment for that as well.

Comment: Same applies for `$item` - using `$item['value']` clearly shows it's also an array.

Comment: However, your answer should probably include how to fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from the PHP Docs:

> Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

You have to use the keys, not the arrays themselves:

```
function sitesync_empty_vals(&$entity) {
$vals = false;
  $entity = (array) $entity;
  foreach ($entity as $field) {
    if (is_array($field)) {
      foreach ($field as $langKey=>$lang) {
    foreach ($lang as $itemKey=>$item) {
      if (isset($item['value'])) {
        if (empty($item['value'])) {
          unset($field[$langKey][$itemKey]);
          break;
        }
        else {
          $vals = true;
        }
      }
    }
      }
      if (!$vals && is_array($lang)) {
    watchdog("field", print_r($field, true));
    unset($field[$langKey]);
      }
    }
  }
```

}